# Align two divs on the same line without modifying the HTML

Tags: css, angularjs, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

What is the best way to align these two `div` on the same line?

```
<div class="main_one">
  <div class="number_one">Title A</div>
</div>
<div class="main_two">
  <div class="number_two">Title B</div>
</div>
<div class="main_three">
  <div class="number_three">Title C</div>
</div>
<div class="main_four">
  <div class="number_four">Title D</div>
</div>
```

Currently I have `Title A` on top of `Title B` from top to bottom looking at the page.

My goal is to have Title A and Title B aligned together on the same line **without using HTML** and **without moving the structure of main_three and main_four.**

Based on the way things I structured, I can only use **css** to achieve that goal.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="main_one">
    <div class="number one">Title A</div>
</div>
<div class="main_two">
    <div class="number two">Title B</div>
</div>

<div class="main_three">
    <div class="number one">Title C</div>
</div>
<div class="main_four">
    <div class="number two">Title D</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .main_one{
        float:left;
    }

    .main_two{
        float:left;
    }

    .main_three{
        clear:both;
        float:left;
    }

    .main_four{
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris. You solution worked but i forgot to include two other divs. basically what happened is that i changed it the way u suggested and `div main_three` and `div main_four` are jeopardized now. I have updated my post above....`main three` and `main_four` should not move. I would love to hear from you

Comment: You can do clear:both; when using main_three.  I'll put answer in code above.

Comment: hum apparently `clear:both` is not the solution. those two divs are not properly aligned anymore. it may be because of the different css used here i cant copy/paste them because its long.

Comment: John,  I did a screenshot to show you how it's aligning in a fresh html doc for me.  Nothing pretty but A & B are side by side and on a new line C & D are below A & B , C & D are side by side as well.   Maybe try incognito mode in Chrome to make sure it's not caching anything when using the clear:both;

Comment: Yes I can see the screenshot....so the problem is the structure of the css here, I will figure it out. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks John. I removed some spacing above to not make the code so long. Hope you get any glitchyness sorted!

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other child in the parent of the two:

```html
<body>
  <div class="main_one">
    <div class="number one">Title A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_two">
    <div class="number two">Title B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

you can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

#### EDIT:

To align only two of the four boxes in the same line I think `inline` would be the correct choice:

```css
.main_one, .main_two {
  display: inline; /* or */
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I forgot to mention the two other `divs`, I have updated my post above....`main three` and `main_four` should not move. please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: `flex` is already applied to that `div container` that u refer to as body in the codebase but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers point out, `flex` on the body works fine, or `floats`.

Or you can use `inline-block`

```css
.main_one,
.main_two {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main_one">
    <div class="number one">Title A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_two">
    <div class="number two">Title B</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I forgot to mention the two other `divs`, I have updated my post above....`main three` and `main_four` should not move. please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This would still work even if you have the third and four divs, since those will automatically be block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the `display` property to `inline` like this

```css
.main_one, .main_two,
.number_one, .number_two {
  display: inline;
}
```

or even shorter and more creative, like this, this will inline everything though.

```css
body * {
  display: inline;
}
```

**EDIT:** The stuff below are no longer the case.

As a side note - you are missing the closing square bracket tag on one of the divs

```html
<div class="main_one">
  <div class="number one">Title A</div>
</div>
<div class="main_two">
  <div class="number two">Title B</div <------------ HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I forgot to mention the two other `divs`, I have updated my post above....`main three` and `main_four` should not move. please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I updated my answer. As an another side note, you are now missing a closing div for this div :)
``<div class="main_two">``